# .net message loop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

Could anyone help to explain how can I interact with message loop in WPF?
I know how to start it using

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
```

Now, I just need a way to call it.
I have a while-loop and I whant to process messages in a message loop from it.

```
while (state == DebuggerStaus.Waiting)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                //>> Here I want to call a message loop <<
            }
```

Waiting for your suggestions. Best regards.

P.S. I need to be able to INVOKE methods into this thread while the thread is being in while-loop. That is my main goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do that on a control which was created on the WPF thread:

```
Action myAction = () =>
{
  textEdit1.Text = "Counter = " + (i++);
};
textEdit1.Dispatcher.Invoke(myAction);
```

Comment: Good solution, but not for this case.
There is no WPF control in that thread. =(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Thread dispatcherThread = Thread.Current// or thread that dispatcher is running on
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(dispatcherThread);
dispatcher.Invoke(myAction);
```